# Can't hide UIImageView via setHidden:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface, uiimageview

I have a custom UITableViewCell in which i create an Icon like this:

```
self.icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 50)];
[self.icon setImage:[AppearanceProxyController getImageForAssetIdentifier:@"import"]];
[self addSubview:self.icon];
```

which works just fine. In addition there is my method to hide the icon:

```
-(void)hideIcon{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.icon setHidden:true];
    });
}
```

which ... has no effect at all and i have no clue why.
the method is called when the cell is tapped from its tableviewcontroller.

the check states it as hidden but it is not.

```
UIImageView: 0x17d37d20; frame = (15 15; 50 50); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x17f8f4c0>> is hidden: 1
```

setting the uiimage to nil od the alpha to 0.0 has no effect either. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're hiding the right instance? Have you, for example, created the image view several times and forgot to `removeFromSuperview` the old instances? Set a breakpoint where you're creating your image view and check whether that breakpoint is reached more often than you'd expected it to.

Comment: What happens if you do it without dispatch block? Is it the same result?

Comment: good hint @DarkDust ! i just realized my awakeFromNib was called twice as i got my cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` via `[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: ...]` and not `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:...]`. This resulted in a new imageView, which was not hidden obviously. I'd be happy to accept this as an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have more than one `UIImageView` instance, but only have a reference to the latest one. When you hide that, you'll see the old instance underneath which (if they show the same image) looks like hiding didn't work.

So you need to make sure that you call `removeFromSuperview` on the old instances or need to make sure that you don't create more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are creating self.icon in every uitableview cell.
You alloc init the icon every time so self.icon hold the last object which you alloc init. if you hide the self.icon then it hides the last object.

So If you want to hide some image view just pass this object in your hide icon method like this

```
-(void)hideIcon : (UIImageView *)imageView{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [imageView setHidden:true];
    });
}
```

And call it when you want to hide

Comment: but the self.icon is in my custom UITableViewCell class so it should always hold the reference of its own unique icon instance only. The Problem was awakeFromNib being called again on tapping the cell which resultet in a "reset"